# Layout Cycle detected when setting Commandbar.ClosedDisplayMode to minimal

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, universal

Since a few days I realized that all of a sudden my application crashes, when the ClosedDisplayMode is set to minimal.

It work before and the only thing I actually changed was putting the View from shared to WindowsPhone specific.

The only place where I override the SizeChanged is to check whether I should show the StatusBar or not. But outcommenting does not help anyway...

Thanks for your inputs

--EDIT--
Ok I got it work again. THe error was somewhere deep down in another one of my components. It seemed that VisualStudio did not update the Xaml Files (although they changed) until I changed from Debug to release...

Comment: the error seems to propagate slowly... now other views throw the same exception, allthough I haven't changed anything related to the views...

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it work again. THe error was somewhere deep down in another one of my components. It seemed that VisualStudio did not update the Xaml Files (although they changed) until I changed from Debug to release...